# What is the simplest way to get the sub dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

x is a dataframe whose index is code and contains a column `pe`.

```
>>>x
     pe  
code                                                                     
01   15
02   30
03   70
04   6
05   40
06   34
07   25
08   65
10   45
12   55
13   32
```

Get the index of x.

```
x.index
Index(['01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07',
       '08', '10', '12','13'],
      dtype='object', name='code', length=11)
```

I want to get a sub dataframe whose index is ['01','04','08','10','12'].

```
x_sub
        pe  
code                                                                     
01   15
04   6
08   65
10   45
12   55
```

What is the simplest way to get the sub dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `loc`

```
x_sub = x.loc[['01','04','08','10','12']]
```

Or if your indexes are integers:

```
x_sub = x.loc[[01,04,08,10,12]]
```